# A difference between set of maps $F^E$ and $F(E, F)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I read in a book of algebra that $F^E$ is the set of values of functions from $E$ to $F$  element are families of élément of F indexed by E $(f(x) :x ∈ E)$ different from $F(E,F)$ where elements are $f$ and $g$.

Comment: It' s not entirely clear what you are asking here - at a minimum please try to use the inline version of LaTeX for math symbols and improve spelling/grammar if possible.  I edited this a bit to illustrate but did not want to try to completely rewrite your intent.

Comment: For sets $X$ and $Y$, $X^Y$ usually denotes the set of all function $Y\to X$.

Comment: I'll add that using $F$ the first time in $F(F,E)$ is not optimal even if it means functions, and in a general category either $F^E$ or $Hom(F,E)$ could be used to mean the same thing.

Comment: @AlgTop1854 Surely $F^E$ is the same as $\mathrm{Hom}(E,F)$ (not from $F$ to $E$), to match the set theory notation.

Comment: Yes, typo on my part and can't edit now!